# How To Rollback Local Install of Google App Engine SDK

Tags: google-app-engine

I have the Google App Engine for Python SDK installed and everything was fine and dandy. I recently updated to the latest version and things are breaking.

Easiest to track down was that `add` on the `Index` class was replaced by `put`. This is a pretty big problem since we are adding to the Index in a `_pre_put_hook`.

I see [Release Notes from Feb 13](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes), but don't see a Breaking Changes document or anything. I'm also not sure when these issues will propagate into the production environment as the app seems to be running without issues in production.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I rollback my local SDK to 1.7.4. I checked out the [svn repo](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/), but I don't know what to do with it.
2. When should I expect these changes to go into effect in production? Am I missing some part of the documentation or some channel/group where I can stay up-to-date on these things? The #appengine channel  Freenode has been really helpful over the past few weeks, but I am hoping that there is a more official place to keep track of news.

**Update**:
I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/Z6XN_64cA7w) saying that Stack Overflow is not the official channel for support. Hopefully that means that this question will be addressed faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can download the 1.7.4 SDK Here (but I recommend that you don't): http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.7.4.zip

2) Production is actually updated to the new SDK before it is released to us (well a partial rollout). This is to test for bugs and such that may prop up prior to doing a mass release. You can stay up to date about SDK releases in the [google-appengine group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!forum/google-appengine)

Part of this SDK's release notes mentions that some features in the Search API were removed from the SDK and will be removed from production on the next version. I assume this included the functions your code depended on. You are also using an "experimental" class that isn't guaranteed to remain backwards compatible so you must be able to quickly adapt to changes in your code when changes like these are made. It's probably in your best interest to modify your code to work around these changes and get it rolled out before the next SDK is finalized (exact dates are unknown but a "pre-release" announcement will be given in the group linked above). You can also try and open an issue on the issue tracker if you really need this feature.

Comment: I see the official announcement [blog post](http://googleappengine.blogspot.in/2013/02/app-engine-175-released.html), but does that mean it has already been deployed to production as well? Or am I missing some date schedule somewhere?

Comment: 1.7.5 has already been pushed into production, yes. The Search API features that were removed from the development SDK in 1.7.5 won't affect production until the next SDK release (1.7.6?). This is so you have time to fix production code with non backwards compatible changes in the SDK before the changes are reflected in production

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit old, but the older responses do not work anymore, so just in case anyone is in my situation and needs an old SDK (haven't upgraded from python 2.5 yet), there's this page: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/. You can look through the pages and just replace everything after the slash with the correct link to the desired SDK.

For example, I needed to download SDK 1.6 for MAC OS, so I ended up using this link (in the address bar): https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/deprecated/160/GoogleAppEngineLauncher-1.6.0.dmg, which I found by doing a search for dmg in the XML page.

Answer (score 1):

Rmove 1.7.5 and download and install the older version.  They're still available.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads

Just look at the actual download link for the OS you're using.  Instead of just clicking on the URL, copy the link and paste it into a new browser window, and change the version number.

I've personally run into SDK upgrade pain a couple of times.  I usually install the sdk into a folder called google_appengine.  I'd routinely rename the old one to a backup name (ie google_appengine_1_7_4) before installing the new one.  If I run into troubles I simply rename the folders around so the new version becomes google_appengine_1_7_5 and I rename the old one back to google_appengine.   Pretty simple.